# Qt Screenshot Example without Timer

Tags: c++, qt, x11

The Qt [Screenshot Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-desktop-screenshot-example.html) uses a timer before it takes a screenshot. Is it possible to edit the example so that the screenshot fires instantly (with "Hide this Window" checked) where the main window is invisible in the final screenshot?

My attempts have not worked. I tried:

```
setVisible(false);
qApp->processEvents();
qApp->sendPostedEvents();
qApp->flush();
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "shootScreenshot", Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

With all above, the main window stays visible in the final screenshot despite hiding the window and processing all possible events.

Can anything be done? Why is this happening?

Comment: Your code snippet raises far more questions than it answers. Why are you manually spinning the event loop?  Why are you using QMetaObject::invokeMethod() to call a method?  Does the "shootScreenshot" method even exist, and if so, where is it defined?

Comment: Without a timer, you are on a race condition with update calls and repaints and what Qt will pull from the graphics buffer.  Just do a small updater timer of like 100 ms, and play a sound at the same time.  If you look at how a lot of other screenshot tools work, they use the same technique, to let you think it is faster than it is.  Your other option is to use a global keyboard shortcut or something instead of clicking a window.

Comment: I think the problem is that there are more parties involved that it may seem. Even it you hide window, and ensure if Qt processes all your events, X server may not have yet hidden it, and even if it did, the window beneath your window may not have yet redrawn itself. You may have to wait not only for your app process its events, but also for X server and other clients too.

Comment: Did you try setHidden(true) method instead of setVisible ?

Comment: I was spinning events in the hope that the repaint happens. I have looked at the Qt source and setHidden simply does setVisible(!bool).

Clicking the Window is something I need - my modified example allows the user to select a region of the screen. Is there any X11 code that may help?